# AngularJS nested ng-repeat how do I reference a child scope from within the parent controller?

Tags: angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this template.html

```
<style>
.sel{ border:5px solid red; }
</style>
<div class="parent-loop" ng-repeat="(datekey,group) in grouped">
    <div class="child-loop" ng-repeat="event in group" side="right">
        <div ng-class="{sel: $index == selected}">
           <label class="date">{{datekey}}</label>
           <button ng-click="$parent.select($index)" class="bt-select">select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this controller.js

```
$scope.events = [{id:event1-date1, startDate:12/3/16},{id:event2-date1, startDate:12/3/16},{id:event1-date2, startDate:22/4/16}];

// this is the result of $scope.events.reduce(...) 
$scope.grouped = {
    '12/3/16':[{id:event1-date1, startDate:12/3/16},'12/3/16':{id:event2-date1, startDate:12/3/16}],
    '22/4/16':[{id:event1-date2, startDate:22/4/16}]
};

// this is called from within an item inside the child loop
$scope.select = function(index){
    $scope.selected = index;
}
```

Note: in the real app, $parent is actually called something else but I simplified for this example; the button is working and calling the function in the controller so nevermind the $parent.select($index).

My issue is: I want to click one of the item's bt-select button and apply the .sel class - this works; In this example I have 2 groups, one with 2 items and another one with 1 item; so we have 2 items with $index=1 (indexed within their own parent loops) and therefore they both get the class. So, how can I reference just the clicked item's scope in the select() function? I need a way to have a "global index" (or something) that allows me to reference just one of the scopes. I managed to do it with an ugly hack where I concatenate parent and child index (a string) and ng-init and then just check that variable in the child but I was thinking there should be a nicer way.

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: <div ng-class="{'sel': ($index == selected) && ($index==1)}"> ?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear: I don't specifically want to select items with $index=1; I want to select only one item, but the problem is that there are multiple items with the same index (one for each of the parent loops). I updated my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version:  http://jsfiddle.net/aLdxg715/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.events = [
      {id:'event1-date1', startDate:'12/3/16'},
      {id:'event2-date1', startDate:'12/3/16'},
      {id:'event1-date2', startDate:'22/4/16'}
    ];

    $scope.grouped = {
        '12/3/16':[{id:'event1-date1', startDate:'12/3/16'},{id:'event2-date1', startDate:'12/3/16'}],
        '22/4/16':[{id:'event1-date2', startDate:'22/4/16'}]
    };

    $scope.select = function(index,groupIndex){
        $scope.selected = index;
        $scope.selectedGroup = groupIndex;
    }
}
```

```css
.sel{ border:5px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="parent-loop" ng-repeat="(datekey,group) in grouped">
    <div class="child-loop" ng-repeat="event in group" side="right">
        <div ng-class="{sel: ($index == selected && datekey == selectedGroup)}">
           <label class="date">{{datekey}}</label>
           <button ng-click="select($index,datekey)" class="bt-select">select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works. I will accept it once you review and accept my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`{{$parent.$index}}`

to access outer ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ng-init on the outer ng-repeat and then check for 2 conditions in the inner ng-repeat, like this:

```
<div class="parent-loop" ng-repeat="(datekey,group) in grouped" ng-init="outerIndex=$index">
    <div class="child-loop" ng-repeat="event in group" side="right">
        <div ng-class="{sel: outerIndex == parent && $index == child}">
           <label class="date">{{datekey}}</label>
           <button ng-click="$parent.select(outerIndex, $index)" class="bt-select">select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in my controller:

```
$scope.select = function(parentIndex,childIndex){
    $scope.parent = parentIndex;
    $scope.child = childIndex;
}
```

Comment: Ataur Rahim Chowdhury also gave a cleaner answer which doesn't need the ng-init directive.